# setting variables between view controllers

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

I'm new to swift and I'm trying to learn how to pass data between view controllers and use firebase along with it. This is my segue to a new controller with it setting a variable on that view controller I'm pushing to.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserInfoViewController") as! UserInfoViewController
    viewController.uidPassed = userUIDArray[indexPath.row]
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

It segues to the new controller where I have the variable declared as a string. When I go to run this it crashes with it saying that the string was empty. I can print it and it is empty in the viewDidAppear method, but the viewDidLoad method it has the UID stored in the variable from when I clicked on in the previous controller. Am I not passing the variable from one view controller to the other correctly?

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    databaseRef.child("Users").child(self.uidPassed).child("Name").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let name = snapshot.value as! String
        print(name)
    })
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. Have you tried to print that uidPassed in your `didSelectRowAt` method? On you storyboard, you are not connecting these two view controller by segue, right?

Comment: That was it. I was connecting them by a segue. I deleted it and it runs flawlessly now.

Comment: I wrap it up and put that in an answer. Basically you are combining the two data passing methods and apparently that doesn't work out. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main ways to pass data from one view controller to another view controller.

First, you can connect your cell with the destination view controller in storyboard. In this case you will define the type of segue in storyboard, and you need to define an identifier for the segue in storyboard. When you want to pass data, you need to do it in `prepareForSegue` method, like this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? YourTableViewController {

        destinationViewController.texts = self.texts
        //...
    }
}
```

Second, you can do this programmatically, like what you are trying to do in your example. In this case you should not connect view controllers by segue in storyboard. Instead, you set an identifier for the destination view controller itself. Then you initiate that controller in the code, set properties to the initiated view controller object and then present it, like what you are doing in your example.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a typing issue. It seems like `userUIDArray` holds an array of UID's (not sure what type this is), and you're trying to assign it to `viewController.uidPassed`, which sounds like it's expecting a string. Try this:

`viewController.uidPassed = userUIDArray[indexPath.row] as! String`

The other option is to change the type of `uidPassed` to whatever type of value the `userUIDArray` variable holds.

Comment: Both the array and variable are of type string.

Comment: Can you update your example with the definition of userUIDArray? Either that isn't holding strings, or that isn't getting assigned it's values properly. You can test this a bit by print the value of userUIDArray at the top of didSelectRowAt.

Comment: Okay I did a test and hooked a button up to that view controller to print that variable, also I set the variable to just a simple string instead of it grabbing from the array. Turns out its not passing that variable over, because it wouldn't print the variable either through the button.

Comment: It's a bad practice to do forced castings ;)